# Openstack - errors in web interface

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack

I have an openstack server, where I deployed 2 VMs. Occasionally I cannot see my VMs (instances) via the web. It looks as if there are no instances, although there are. It's inconsistent. Sometimes I do see them and sometimes not.

The error message I'm getting is

> ERROR: Unable to retrieve instances

I did not find anything suspicious in the `nova-compute.log`.

Answer (score 0):

It is latency issue Your Openstack looks very slow when this error happens so Horizon times out before it gets response from nova API.

Check why it is slow , it could be also network latency issue if you have multi node deployment.